# XSLT: How to update element from other xml document?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I need to update an element, BrightcoveVideoID in an xml document by matching a different element in another xml document. The common element is called LegacyId.

The original xml has 10 items (2 items are shown here) Each item is enclosed in tags, PubFactoryMetadata. Each PubFactoryMetadata tag set has a LegacyID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Content>
    <PubFactoryMetadata>
        <RSuite_Id>W1735_XYZ.xml</RSuite_Id>
        <regular_title>Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm</regular_title>
        <content_type>Video</content_type>
        <content_type_subtype>Classic Patient Ed</content_type_subtype>
        <LegacyId>W1735 </LegacyId>
        <BrightcoveVideoID>W1735</BrightcoveVideoID>
    </PubFactoryMetadata>

    <PubFactoryMetadata>
        <file>videos-v2_W1739_Metadata_es.xml</file>
        <RSuite_Id>W1739_XYZ.xml</RSuite_Id>
        <regular_title>Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm</regular_title>
        <content_type>Video</content_type>
        <content_type_subtype>Classic Patient Ed</content_type_subtype>
        <LegacyId>W1739</LegacyId>
        <BrightcoveVideoID>W1739</BrightcoveVideoID>
    </PubFactoryMetadata>
</Content>
```

The Update file has a LegacyId and BrightcoveVideoID. I need to match the LegacyId element in the original and the update and then update copy the BrightcoveVideoID to the original.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Content>
   <PubFactoryMetadata>
       <LegacyId>W1735_testering</LegacyId>
       <BrightcoveVideoID>66063558001</BrightcoveVideoID>
   </PubFactoryMetadata>
   <PubFactoryMetadata>
        <LegacyId>W1739</LegacyId>
        <BrightcoveVideoID>66063562001</BrightcoveVideoID>
    </PubFactoryMetadata>
    <PubFactoryMetadata>
        <LegacyId>K1892</LegacyId>
        <BrightcoveVideoID>5273514858001</BrightcoveVideoID>
    </PubFactoryMetadata>
</Content>
```

The desired output is to have each PubFactoryMetadata item set is to have the BrightcoveVideoID updated from the update file.

```
<Content>
<PubFactoryMetadata>
<RSuite_Id>W1735_XYZ.xml</RSuite_Id>
        <regular_title>Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm</regular_title>
        <content_type>Video</content_type>
         <content_type_subtype>Classic Patient Ed</content_type_subtype>
        <LegacyId>W1735</LegacyId>
        <BrightcoveVideoID>66063558001</BrightcoveVideoID>
    </PubFactoryMetadata>

<PubFactoryMetadata>
    <file>videos-v2_W1739_Metadata_es.xml</file>
    <RSuite_Id>W1739_XYZ.xml</RSuite_Id>
    <regular_title>Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm</regular_title>
    <content_type>Video</content_type>
    <content_type_subtype>Classic Patient Ed</content_type_subtype>
    <LegacyId>W1739</LegacyId>
    <BrightcoveVideoID>66063562001</BrightcoveVideoID>
</Content>
```

Here is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <!-- fileName = update information file name
     updates = document to be updated -->
    <xsl:param name="fileName" select="'PF_Update.xml'"/>
    <xsl:param name="updates" select="document($fileName)"/>

    <!-- Update_Data = orginal node tree -->
    <xsl:variable name="Update_BrightCoveId"       select="$updates/Content/PubFactoryMetadata/BrightcoveVideoID"/>

<!--Identity -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- In the original match -->
<xsl:template match="PubFactoryMetadata">

    <xsl:copy>
        LegacyId: <xsl:value-of select="LegacyId"/>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="$Update_BrightCoveId" />

    </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've tried several examples but I haven't been able to figure out how to match one LegacyID and then update the BrightCoveId in the original to a result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a key that enables you to find things quickly in your lookup document:

```
<xsl:key name="lookup" match="PubFactoryMetadata" use="LegacyID"/>
```

Then define your template rule like this:

```
<xsl:template match="BrightcoveVideoID">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of 
         select="key('lookup', ../LegacyID, document($filename))
                 /BrightcoveVideoID"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked great, thank you! Here is a complete listing of the stylesheet.

```
<!-- fileName = update information file name
     updates = document to be updated -->
<xsl:param name="fileName" select="'PF_Update.xml'"/>
<xsl:param name="updates" select="document($fileName)"/>

<!-- Create a key for LegacyID -->
<xsl:key name="lookup" match="PubFactoryMetadata" use="LegacyId"/>

<!--Identity: make a copy of all the nodes -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

     <!-- In the original match BrightcoveVideoID from update and copy it to the original -->
     <xsl:template match="BrightcoveVideoID">

         <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:value-of select="key('lookup', ../LegacyId, document($fileName))/BrightcoveVideoID"/>
         </xsl:copy>

         <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```